# Issue with increasing the size of the highlighted area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently i am working on a requirement, which user can click on the plotted area of a semi circle chart and increase the size of the hovered portion of the plotted area in semi cycle chart....I have gone through the Highchart API and come up with an solution, but my code snitpet is not working..can any one help me with this please.

```js
this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', 
    {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        height: 400,        
        plotShadow: false
      },
      title: {
        text: '98',
        style: {
          "fontSize": "48px"
        },
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 50
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
     },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Test: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
        enabled:false
      },
      colors: ['#FF0000', '#FFA500', '#FFFF00'],
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            distance: -100,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: 'white'
            }
          },
          point: {
              events: {
                click: function (e) {
                  alert("Clicked");
                }
              }
            },
          startAngle: -90,
          endAngle: 90,
          center: ['50%', '75%'],
          size: '110%'
        }
      },
      series:[
        {
           data: [
            {y: 1, name:"", id:"0"}, 
            { y: 7, name:"",  id:"1"},
            { y: 2, name:"", id:"2"}
           ],
           innerSize: '65%',
            type: 'pie',

        }
     ]
    }

  );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Aravinda Meewalaarachchi, I do not quite understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to get the same effect after point click as point hover? Also check `allowPointSelect` option: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h3xskctp/

Comment: Yes this is the answer i was expected..Please put it as answer and i will accept that..Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `allowPointSelect` property to true:

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h3xskctp/